# How do I pivot my table to show two separate columns

Tags: postgresql, pivot, metabase

(my database shows me each individual person and how much of a payout they have and at which stage they have it - f.y.i not every person has all 4 payouts)

I have created a table with averages for different stages called payout1, payout 2, payout 3 and payout 4.

Each stage has a payout amount and there are multiple people that get a different payout amount.

I am now having an issue to pivot this table so that i can have 2 columns with the payout stage and the average. I need this so that I can use this as a bar chart visualization in metabase.

I have got the stage where i can easily show the averages (see below)

```
select 
    round(avg(payout_1)::numeric,2) as avg_payout_1,
    round(avg(payout_2)::numeric,2) as avg_payout_2,
    round(avg(payout_3)::numeric,2) as avg_payout_3,
    round(avg(payout_4)::numeric,2) as avg_payout_4
    from payout_table
```

The result is that i see the averages per payout (yay) however now i want to have the 2 columns, 1 saying the payout type and 2. the average amount payed out

This is my outcome:

```
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|   avg_payout_1   |  avg_payout_2 |  avg_payout_3 |  avg_payout_4 |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|       34.32      |      145.11   |     78.65     |      96.76    |
|------------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
```

I would like it to show:

```
|------------------|---------------|
|      payout      |      avg      |  
|------------------|---------------|
|     payout_1     |      34.32    | 
|------------------|---------------|
|     payout_2     |      145.11   | 
|------------------|---------------|
```

etc

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output

Comment: @S-Man I just added it, thanks for commenting so quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `unnest()`:

```
select 
    unnest(array[
        'payout_1', 
        'payout_2', 
        'payout_3', 
        'payout_4']) as payout,
    unnest(array[
        round(avg(payout_1)::numeric,2),
        round(avg(payout_2)::numeric,2),
        round(avg(payout_3)::numeric,2),
        round(avg(payout_4)::numeric,2)]) as avg
from payout_table
```

or `jsonb`:

```
select key as payout, value::numeric as avg
from (
    select
        round(avg(payout_1)::numeric,2) as payout_1,
        round(avg(payout_2)::numeric,2) as payout_2,
        round(avg(payout_3)::numeric,2) as payout_3,
        round(avg(payout_4)::numeric,2) as payout_4
    from payout_table
    ) s
cross join jsonb_each(to_jsonb(s))
```

[Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=dbc6978107a3281173dcd7409756f137)

Answer (score 0):

If you have only those 4 columns, you could make an array of those values and then split them into rows, like:

```
select
unnest(array [a1,a2,a3,a4]),
unnest(array ['avg_payout_1','avg_payout_2','avg_payout_3','avg_payout_4'])
from(
select 
    round(avg(payout_1)::numeric,2) a1,
    round(avg(payout_2)::numeric,2) a2,
    round(avg(payout_3)::numeric,2) a3,
    round(avg(payout_4)::numeric,2) a4
    from payout_table) a
```

This is not the nicest looking solution, but it works.